# Form target not being set to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I'm working on a project where I need to change via javascript the target of a form so that it's response opens in an iframe. So I have an iframe 'frame' and in my javascript I have a function on a button as follows:

```
  $('.form').target = "frame";
  $('.form').trigger('submit.rails');
```

However this seems to still open the form in a new page rather than in the iframe, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is nothing about Rails.

Comment: I included rails in the tag since it is a rails form and I am using 'rails.submit' to submit the form, which I thought might be effecting the result.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out I had to use:

```
$('.form').attr("target","frame")
```